# How to run a range of value in specified seconds in Flash?

Tags: actionscript-3, flash, timer, actionscript, range

How do I update a range of values in a specified time? I am new to Flash ActionScript 3.

Assume I want the user to see values from 0 to 90 in 4 seconds, how do I do that in Flash AS3? This is my attempt so far:

```
var valueRange:Number = 90; //90 different values
var myTimer:Timer = new Timer(1000,valueRange); //should repeat valueRange times
myTimer.addEventListener(TimerEvent.TIMER, rangeFunction); //function
myTimer.start();

function rangeFunction(event:TimerEvent):void {
myText_txt.text = String((-1)+myTimer.currentCount);
}
```

For every second, the value will be updated making it 90 seconds long.

Please kindly help, as this is fundamental need for my animations.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You need to scale your values to map one range to the other.

To go from 0 to 90 in 4 seconds, you'll have 90 / 4 or 22.5 values per second. So on every tick of your timer, you'd increment by 22.5 to go from 0 to 90 in 4 seconds.

This probably doesn't look as good as I'm guessing you'd prefer to see the numbers whiz by. One method of making this happen can be to use a smaller timer update interval, say 100ms instead of updating once every second. Since 100ms means 0.1 second, you'd have an increment value of 2.25 every 100ms.

You could go all the way down and work out an interval value small enough that you can increment by 1, but having really small interval values may not be a good thing for a Timer.

Comment: unfortunately, timer does not sync in the long run, it randomly slows down

Comment: Interesting. I don't think I've had that issue before. I do know that the Timer fire event can be affected by your frame rate, so you could avoid a timer altogether and use the event frame event. This may look slightly better too as on every frame update the display value would update as well in sync. Another thing you can do is check if you have some processing intensive code, which can also affect timers (both of these points are mentioned in the Timer class documentation).

Comment: whoops, checking back, I meant the "enter frame" event, not "event frame event"

Comment: Yes, I did that, but do you have any idea of slowing the value down every 5 frames, do you think applying modulo aoperator like currentFrame%5 will work?

Comment: What do you mean by 'slowing the value'? Doing currentFrame%5 will allow you to find every 5th frame, but what you do from there is up to you.

Comment: I resolved this issue using ENTER_FRAME Event Listener. I just decided to increase the value each frame. This never let me down.

You could just change your answer to a random example that uses ActionScript 3, and you can have the answer

Comment: I try to write my answers for these types of questions as just logic, which can be implemented in any language. It really is just about the math in this case anyhow and the ENTER_FRAME event listener is just acting as a generic loop (whether it be a game loop, a procedural loop, or an repeating event listener loop). In any case, glad you figured it out and I won't be annoyed if you choose to not accept this.